# FileMaker Pro:- Signature document capture in Windows

Tags: webview, filemaker

I am trying to implement signature capture for windows using FM Pro 16.I have written some script on save button which is working fine on MAC but for windows t's not. Please see the below script :-

```
¶           // Save button.         
¶           var saveButton = document.getElementById(\"save-button\");
¶           saveButton.addEventListener(\"click\", function (event) {
¶           
¶               // If the signature pad isn't empty...
¶               if (! signaturePad.isEmpty() ) {
¶
¶                   // Convert the canvas into a data URL.
¶                   var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();
¶           
¶                   // Encode the data.
¶                   var_encoded = encodeURIComponent ( dataURL );
¶           
¶                   // Prep the URL to use for the hand-off to FM.
¶                   var fullURL = '" & fmpurl & "&param=' + var_encoded;
¶           
¶                   // Send the data to FM.
¶                   window.location = fullURL;                                  
¶                   
¶               };
```

I have implemented and HTML using Web Viewer

Script:-

Base64Decode ( Substitute ( Get ( ScriptParameter ); "data:image/png;base64,"; "" ); "FMEasySignature.png" )

Implemented Demo Located at :- 
http://timdietrich.me/fmeasysignature/downloads.php

Comment: Since this is not supported by developer, you will have to find and integrate a library what supports Windows.

Answer (score 0):

At http://timdietrich.me/fmeasysignature/downloads.php it says:

Sorry, but FMEasySignature is not compatible with FileMaker Pro for Windows.

Comment: yeah but the script which he has used i want to configure the same for windows